# How do I control for pscore?

Tags: propensity-scores, conditional-independence

I see that people usually implement pscore matching or control for pscore fixed effects. Why do I need to do pscore matching? Why can't I just include pscore as a continuous variable in my regression as follows?

$$Y_i = \alpha + \beta D_i + \delta p(X_i) + \epsilon_i$$

Why do I have to run:

$$Y_i = \alpha + \beta D_i + \sum \delta_k \mathbb1\{p(X_i) = p\} + \epsilon_i$$